# Build Mobile App for alexa?

Tags: android, hybrid-mobile-app, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

Hi I have a custom skill running with alexa echo & is working fine. Now I need to build a mobile application (android native / Hybrid) that take input from my phone's mic, alexa processes this with my custom skill & return output that plays from my phone's speakers.

In short, I need an app doing all all echo is doing. Is it possible ? How ? And if yes, please provide me links that can be helpful. Any samples would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes we are able to create the app like the alexa.

Will give you the blueprint of that.

1. You go through the google for the SpeechRecognizer in the android to start the app to listen to the speech and you will receive the text that is detected.
2. Use this text as input to the wit.ai search for the wit.ai the AI engine that will procees the context for the speech. You can attach your own alexa skills to that. The Wit.ai will return you the respected response back to the app.
3. Using the TextToSpeech engine of android api you can make the app to speak out to the user.
4. Also aditionally use the Sphinx-library that will help you to create the app that will wake up and will start recognizing with the key words like "ok- google", "alexa". You can configure your own.

Hope this would be helpful to you. Please do google for the steps.
I have created the similar app which you are looking for and have written the custom framework for maintain the context.Since it is proprietary, i cannot share it as a sample.

Answer (score 1):

Alexa does have an SDK using which you can build what you're looking for. 
https://github.com/alexa/alexa-avs-sample-app/tree/master/samples/androidCompanionApp
This is the link to their companion app.

https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-voice-service/content/avs-api-overview
This is their voice service API which states that you can access third party skills.

Answer (score 0):

you need to :

1. Registering Your Product and Creating a Security Profile
2. Generating Self-Signed Certificates
3. Building and Running the Android Mobile Apps
4. Running the Server
5. Running the Client

check this for full [details](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-voice-service/docs/reference-implementation-guide)